# Acceleration of 2 bodies tied with a string

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism

> Find the acceleration of the block of mass $M$ shown in the figure. The coefficient of friction between the two blocks is $\mu_1$ and that between the bigger block and the ground is $\mu_2$.

[image]

Could someone help solve this problem by using Lagrangian mechanics?
I know the solution to this problem using Newtonian mechanics. However, I am not finding the same answer when I am trying to do it using Lagrangian mechanics.

> Answer - $a=\frac{[2m-\mu_2(M+m)]g}{M+m(5-2(\mu_1-\mu_2))}$